# Reference wordpress custom fields (on homepage)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm playing around with the get_meta stuff in wordpress but can't quite figure it out. I created the custom field 'vlink' and am now trying to call that value in another spot on the post page. I checked wordpress documentation but I can't figure it out.I'm trying to create a button which when clicked redirects to a webpage as defined in the custom field. Also should I set the whole   thing as the custom value or can I just define the destination web page. A clearer explanation of how to implement this from another source would also be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably something along those lines:

```
<?php $postmeta = get_post_meta($post->ID); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $postmeta['vlink'][0]; ?>">Linktext</a>
```

To debug, use a var_dump, eg:
 `var_dump($post)`, `var_dump($postmeta)`